# How to implement ngOnDestroy() correctly in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a child component with a timer, every 2 second I send api call to the server. I need to do this call as long as the user is on the page even if he/she going to a wedding and leave the page (the parent compoent window) open.

Here is some code from my component:

```
this.myTimer = Observable.timer(1, 2000);
    this.myTimer
        .mergeMapTo(this.myService.doSomeWork(this.myId))
        .subscribe((data) => {
                this.myData = data;                
            }, (errRes)=>{
            console.log(errRes);
        });
```

And here is the destroy method:

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.myTimer.complete();
  }
```

I simply click on the menu to different component and see that the calls
to the sever is still happening.
I've tried even to close the window (the tab from  chrome browser), still the  calls to server remains.

Any idea why the ngOnDestroy doesn't get called ?

**UPDATE**
I'm using "rxjs": "^5.5.12",

from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.11",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-select-ex": "^3.6.10",
    "ngx-select-options": "^1.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm.. You can try using RxJS's [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html) operator instead.

First and foremost, you import `takeUntil` and `Subject` into your component.

```
import { takeUntil, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
```

Next,

```
unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();
```

And then,

```
this.myTimer
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(this.myService.doSomeWork(this.myId)),
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
  ).subscribe((data) => {
    this.myData = data;                
  }, (errRes)=>{
    console.log(errRes);
  });
```

Do take note that `takeUntil` must be the last operator on your `pipe()` to prevent any observables from 'leaking' out.

And on your ngOnDestroy,

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe.next();
  this.unsubscribe.complete();
}
```

Comment: mergeMapTo is not recognise. I get [ts] Cannot find name 'mergeMapTo'.

Comment: @user2304483 use `mergeMap` instead of `mergeMapTo`. I've updated my answer

Comment: [ts] Cannot find name 'mergeMap'.

Comment: mport {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMapTo';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

Comment: Oh wait @user2304483 , may I know what rxjs version are you using? `import { takeUntil, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: @user2304483 tbh.. I can barely remember the import syntax for rxjs 5. But the example I have stated above is for rxjs 6. Other than that, the types of operators used are the same. I am pretty sure the approach is the same for both RxJS 5 and 6

Comment: I'm using rxjs observable in other components with no problem.

Comment: I've upgrade to rxjs 6 and to angular 8! I marked this answer to solved.

Answer (score 3):

Well, observables are asynchronous patterns. They are based on push rather than pull strategy i.e. when they got data, they push data to the subscriber. Now, you must take caution while working with them as they continue to push data even when the component destroys. You need to explicitly unsubscribe from the observable.
In ngOnDestroy() lifecycle hook you need this piece of code too.

```
this.myTimer.unsubscribe()
```

And that's it, you will not get more data. Alternatively, you can use takeWhile() or takeUntil() approach. Have a look-
https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/