# angular Subscription.add Method vs takeUntil

Tags: angular, rxjs

What the better way to unsubscribe observable in your opinion? (Subscription.add or takeUntil).I think what Subscription.add better because for takeUntil need excess observable

Comment: The best way is not to subscribe in the first place. Use the `async` pipe

Comment: can you add your example?
It will be easier to answer with more data

Comment: This should be reopened. The question mentions two different approaches and what is the difference between them. It's not very much opinion-based imho.

Comment: @C_Ogoo If you are using Angular, you should be using observables rather than converting it into a promise

Comment: Quite a few similar questions which discusses the different approaches when it comes to handling subscriptions and unsubscriptions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428791/angular-rxjs-observable-takeuntil-vs-unsubscribe-with-a-subscription/58429338#58429338, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672547/how-to-implement-ngondestroy-correctly-in-angular-5/56673005#56673005, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460256/angular-observables-do-i-need-unsubscribe-if-no-subscription/58460534#58460534)

Comment: take a look at this https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/

Comment: it's better to use subscription, because takeUntil requires you to put it in the right place(usually last). Subscription will always unsubscribe without any issue. I always prefer it

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation, you could just use `async` pipe in the template for automatic `unsubscription` and `takeUntil` operator if you are using an observable in the component.

Answer (score 0):

As Lex Caraig mentioned, you could just use `async` pipe in the template. But when it comes to component, you need understand the pros & cons of both `unsubscribe` and ```takeUntil operator.

Personally I prefer to use `subscription.add` & `subscription.unsubscribe` than `takeUntil`, because of its side-effects. Please go through the below article to understand more about the side-effects.

https://cartant.medium.com/rxjs-avoiding-takeuntil-leaks-fb5182d047ef