# Why switchMap does not cancel repeated request?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

The request is executed on the server:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params) => {
          return this.spdModelManagerService
            .getSpdModelManager()
            .getOrderDefinitionVersions(params.get("orderid"));
        }),

        finalize(() => {
        })
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log("aa");
      });
  }
```

If you do f5 many times or go through the route, requests are always sent to the server and are not canceled by `switchMap ((params) => {})`. From all requests comes the answer.

Should I use resolvers or what? If user a lot of time requests a route, it sends a lot of requests

Comment: First thing you cannot stop sending calls, but the ongoing call will be cancelled if a new request is sent. When you press F5, you are destroying a component. Then you should have a code of unsubscribe call in ngDestroy.

Comment: How to be then if I switcing routes fast and components sends the same requests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement ngOnDestroy() correctly in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56672547/how-to-implement-ngondestroy-correctly-in-angular)

Comment: I did not get you, what is your network tab display? can you attach a screenshot? And what do you really want it to be?

Comment: Lets assume you have two links: cats, dogs. Clicking on component Cats requests server, when I click over dogs it also requests data. If use do this so fast it sends a lot of requests to server, not canceling the same.

Comment: Seems it is route feature, each time it recreates component and sends data. So switchMap can not work, because when I leave component to another using route it destoies observer.

Comment: Maybe to use resolvers and if it allows to cancel resolver if I go to another route

Comment: You need to unsubscribe calls using takeUntil inside ngDestroy of your component class. It will stop the ongoing request as soon as you click on another link.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21961

Comment: Could you share example?

Comment: I have tried takeUntil and ngDestroy, it does not work, it is still sends requests when I left route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of a hack but this is similar to something I've done when caching certain requests. Essentially if the input to the get is the same and the response will always be the same you can cache the observable inside a property on a service and use shareReplay to just re-emit the last emitted value. Then if the input changes overwriting the property results in a new observable being resolved to return the new value.

example service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, timer, of } from "rxjs";
import { publishReplay, map, shareReplay } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
  private savedObs$: Observable<any>;
  private lastId: number;

  constructor() {}

  get(id: number) {
    const randomReturnValue = Math.random();

    if (this.lastId !== id) {
      this.lastId = id;
      this.savedObs$ = of(id).pipe(
        shareReplay(1),
        map(x => randomReturnValue)
      );
    }

    return this.savedObs$;
  }
}
```

component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) {
    // To show that the same value is returned for the first 7 calls to the observable
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i += 1) {
      if (i < 7) {
        this.exampleService.get(1).pipe(
          tap(x => {
            console.log(x);
          })
        ).subscribe();
      } else {
        this.exampleService.get(i).subscribe(x => {
          console.log(x);
        });
      }
    }

  }
}
```

If you open up the console in the Stackblitz you can see that the same value is returned for the first seven calls due to the id being the same and then changes afterwards each time a new id is passed. Admittedly it's a bit of a kludge but it might get you what you need.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dioyr